# CF10 CFSPREADSHEET Column Names - escaping special characters

Tags: coldfusion, cfspreadsheet

So apparently I can't use any special characters, not even abbreviate with a dot for setting column names in cfspreadsheet. Is there a way to get around this? I'm basically dumping my query results into an excel file using cfspreadsheet and need to retain certain characters such as the dot sign to abbreviate certain terms. It'd be nice to actually take it to the next level and use special characters in these column names too. Is there a work around to this?

Code Sample.

```
<cfset qryColumnList = "CaseNo,Model,Name" />
<cfset qryResultSet = QueryNew(qryColumnList) />

<cfoutput query="getUsedCars">
                <cfset QueryAddRow(qryResultSet, 1) />
                <cfset querySetCell(qryResultSet, "CaseNo", caseno EQ "&nbsp;" ? "" : caseno) />
                <cfset querySetCell(qryResultSet, "Model", model EQ "&nbsp;" ? "" : model) />
                <cfset querySetCell(qryResultSet, "Name", name EQ "&nbsp;" ? "" : name) />                      
</cfoutput>

<cfscript>
                xlsxopencases = SpreadsheetNew("opencases",true);
                SpreadsheetAddRow(xlsxopencases,qryColumnList);
                SpreadsheetAddRows(xlsxopencases,qryResultSet);
                strFileName=GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) & "OpenCasesReport.xlsx";
                SpreadsheetFormatRow(xlsxopencases, {bold="true"}, 1);
                SpreadsheetFormatRows(xlsxopencases, {dataformat="text"}, "1-#qryResultSet.recordcount + 1#");
                SpreadsheetFormatColumn(xlsxopencases, {dataformat="dd/MM/yy HH:mm:SS"},18);
</cfscript>

<cfspreadsheet action="write"
                                                   filename="#strFileName#"
                                                   name="xlsxopencases"
                                                   sheet="1"
                                                   sheetname="OpenCasesReport"
                                                   overwrite="true" />

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=OpenCasesReport.xlsx">
<cfcontent file="#strFileName#" type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />

<cffile action="delete" file="#strFileName#" />
</cfif>
```

Comment: Can you post a small stand-alone example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: added code where the issue is occuring. i'm editing the cfset with columnlist and trying to abbreviate by adding the . or in some cases I actually need to use special characters for some of the column names, where html entities need to be used.

Comment: You don't actually say what the result is beyond "not what you want". Does it error? If so, what is the error? Does it ignore anything other than A-Z? I don't see in your example where any dots or special characters are that actually demonstrate the issue? Can you pls provide stand-alone, self-contained code that actually demonstrates what you're seeing, and fully describe what you're seeing and how that differs from what you want. Reading: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html

Comment: Please post the error message.  I suspect it has more to do with your query column names than your spreadsheet column names.

Answer (score 3):

So I think what you are asking is how you can use a column name of something like `Case No…`. In which case you'll be getting an error like: `The column name Case No… is invalid` when you're passing that into `QueryNew`. I'm also assuming that the column names you are trying to use are dynamic.

What you can do is strip out any of the invalid characters when creating the query and then populate the query with data using the valid column names. Then when you create the spreadsheet just use the original column names.

I've simplified your example and changed it so that it will produce the result I *think* you want :)

```
<!--- the wanted spreadsheet column headers with special chars in --->
<cfset headersList = "Name,Case No…">
<!--- strip out invalid characters so can use as query column names --->
<cfset qryColumnList = reReplaceNoCase(headersList, "[^a-z0-9,]", "", "all")>
<cfset qryResultSet = QueryNew(qryColumnList)>

<!--- add some data to the query object... --->
<cfset queryAddRow(qryResultSet)>
<cfset querySetCell(qryResultSet, "Name", "Hellip")>
<!--- note that instead of referring to the field as 'Case No…' using 'CaseNo' --->
<cfset querySetCell(qryResultSet, "CaseNo", "this text is truncated…")>

<cfscript>
xlsxopencases = SpreadsheetNew("opencases",true);
// note: using the headersList variable which has special chars in it
SpreadsheetAddRow(xlsxopencases,headersList);
SpreadsheetAddRows(xlsxopencases,qryResultSet);
strFileName=GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) & "OpenCasesReport.xlsx";
SpreadsheetFormatRow(xlsxopencases, {bold="true"}, 1);
SpreadsheetFormatRows(xlsxopencases, {dataformat="text"}, "1-#qryResultSet.recordcount + 1#");
</cfscript>

<cfspreadsheet action="write"
    filename="#strFileName#"
    name="xlsxopencases"
    sheet="1"
    sheetname="OpenCasesReport"
    overwrite="true">

<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=OpenCasesReport.xlsx">
<cfcontent file="#strFileName#" type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet">
```

This will produce a spreadsheet that looks like:

```
------------------------------------
| Name   | Case No…                |
------------------------------------
| Hellip | this text is truncated… |
------------------------------------
```

I hope I've understood your question correctly!

Comment: I made the same assumption, but the code in the question does not support it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not entirely clear - I read the comment `i'm editing the cfset with columnlist and trying to abbreviate by adding the .` and made a guess!